# What should I do when the state data become to large?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

This is what I have:

```
state.groupTypes.list=[];
```

The list will have items when I call api and save it to the state tree state.groupTypes.list

```
//with paging and 10 item per page
getList(params)
```

I'm afraid when the state.groupType.list have more than a thoundsand of record it will consume all the memory of the device so I find a solution: the state should only save maximum of 100 record. So when its come to page 10, the state will remove first 10 record and push the new ones get  from api.
Is there any suggestion to solve this problem and is my solution possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the contents of the object doesn't matter in terms of storing it in the state. The object isn't copied, it's referenced.

But if people aren't managed by the component, then it isn't part of the state of the component, so the state isn't where it should be. The component should just close over an import of that data, or use a context representing that data, or receive it in props, etc.

Having large data in the React state is perfectly fine. There isn't really a limit to what you can store there and React state itself doesn't put any type of limitation on the size it can store.

The issue with large data sets appears with rendering such data. If you have for example a table that needs to render thousands of rows, it will slow down the browser. We're talking about thousands of entries though, hundreds shouldn't be a problem at all.

If you find yourself having to render thousands of data points, you can use components/libraries that help with this such as React Virtualized, which will only render the needed elements, rather than all of them.

As you can see, the problem is not what you store but what you render. My recommendation is to not worry about what you're rendering until you notice a performance issue, once you hit that point you will need to start optimizing.

Unless you're sure you will have a performance issue, optimizing from the start can make you lose time better spent elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case, records could reach a thousand. Can you tell how much ram an object usually cost or the way to count it?

Answer (score 0):

you should make an API with pagination support
assume you want to implement infinity scroll in your app  , you send a request  to the server for example "https://www.example.com/list/page1"
and response that you will receive  an array with 5 items and when user scroll to bottom the list you again send a request to server "https://www.example.com/list/page2"

it's all

Comment: I know how paging work. The problem is when you load to page 500, the state tree will save an array of 500 items which may cause the memory problem